# Sharepoint REST service URI

Tags: 2013, office-365, rest

I have one doubt in Sharepoint REST service URI

http://server/site/_api/web/lists and  http://server/site/_api/lists are same request, Am I correct? I mean both request returning same result.

**_api/Web** is SP.WEB

**_api/site** is SP.SITE

So when I am sending any request URI without **/web/** is consider as web level request only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since SharePoint REST endpoint `http://server/site/_api/` returns *service reference* and `http://server/site/_api/web` returns an *appropriate entry point* ( [SP.Web resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288.aspx) in this case) the specified requests are not identical. 
For example, the request:

`http://server/site/_api/web/title` will return `SP.Web Title` property

but the request:

`http://server/site/_api/title` will return the error:

> Cannot find resource for the request title

From another hand, since `_api/lists` is *an alias* to `_api/web/lists` url, the following requests

```
http://server/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')
```

and

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Pages')
```

will return the same [SP.List resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245826.aspx).

### References

[Determine SharePoint REST service endpoint URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556.aspx)